# No constructor with 3 arguments defined in class?

Tags: java, xml, spring

Let me clear it, I'm a completely beginner in `Spring framework`.

I've three class files, Now i'm getting an error into beans.xml. You could take a look into my codes.

Here is `MyAddress.java`:

```
package com.project;

public class MyAddress {
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String address;

    public void Address(String city, String state, String address){
        this.city=city;
        this.state=state;
        this.address=address;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return city+" "+state+" "+address;
    }
}
```

Here is my `Employee.java`

```
package com.project;

public class Employee {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private MyAddress address;

    public Employee(){
        System.out.print("Default constructor..");
    }

    public void Employee(int id, String name, MyAddress address){
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
        this.address=address;
    }

    public void show(){
        System.out.println(id+" "+name);
        System.out.println(address.toString());
    }
}
```

Here is my `MainProgram.java`

```
package com.project;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class MainProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        ApplicationContext ac=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");

        Employee em=(Employee)ac.getBean("e");

        em.show();
    }
}
```

and finally here is my `beans.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="e" class="com.project.MyAddress">
        <constructor-arg value="USA" type="String"></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg value="Delhi" type="String"></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg value="Bangalore" type="String"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="e2" class="com.project.Employee">
        <constructor-arg value="123" type="int"></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg value="raj"></constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
            <ref bean="e"/>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

I'm getting an error in `beans.xml` files as `No constructor with 3 arguments defined in class`

PLease help, what's that mean?

***Surely, help would be appreciated!!***

Comment: There is no return type for a Constructor in java so `public Employee(int id, String name, MyAddress address){`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This

```
public void Address(String city, String state, String address)
```

should be

```
public MyAddress(String city, String state, String address)
```

You got the class name wrong in your constructor, and in addition, constructors don't have a return type.

You have a similar error for `Employee` :

```
public void Employee(int id, String name, MyAddress address)
```

should be

```
public Employee(int id, String name, MyAddress address)
```

Comment: yeah!! you were right!! what a silly mistakes... :p thanks ... ;)

Answer (score 0):

The address class has a default constructor. Omit `void` keyword from method.

Answer (score 0):

As defined [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html),
"A class contains constructors that are invoked to create objects from the class blueprint. Constructor declarations look like method declarations—except that they use the name of the class and have no return type"

Answer (score 0):

In the `MyAddress` class instead of creating a constructor you created a `Address` method,
changing `public void Address(...)` to `public MyAddress(...)` will make it work